# How to verify that we have logged in correctly to a website using requests in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I used requests to login to a website using the correct credentials initially. Then I tried the same with some invalid username and password. I was still getting response status of 200. I then understood that the response status tells if the corresponding webpage has been hit or not. So now my doubt is how to verify if I have really logged in to the website using correct credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP status codes are usually meant for the browsers, or in case of APIs for the client talking to the server. For normal web sites, using status codes for semantical error information is not really useful. Overusing the status codes there could even cause the browser to not render responses correctly.

So for normal HTML responses, you would usually expect a code 200 for almost everything.

In order to check for errors, you will then have to check the—application specific—error output from the HTML response. A good way to find out about these signs is to just try logging in from the browser with invalid credentials and then check what output is rendered. Or as many sites also show some kind of user menu once you’re logged in, check for its existence to figure out if you’re logged in. And when it’s not there, the login probably failed.

Answer (score 0):

What status code the site responds with depends entirely on their implementation; you're more likely to get a non-200 response if you're attempting to log in to a web service. If a login attempt yielded a non-200 response on a normal website, it'd require a special handler on their end, as opposed to a 200 response with a normal page prompting you (presumably a human user, not a script) with a visual cue indicating login failure.

If the site you're logging into returns a 200 regardless of success or failure, you may need to use something like lxml or BeautifulSoup to look for indications of success or failure (which presumably you'll be using already to process whatever it is you're logging in to access).

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is shown below:

```
p_session = requests.Session()    
signin_response = p_session.post(signin_url,
                                 data=logininfo,
                                 headers=headers,
                                 verify=False,#verify ssl
                                 )
#print out the response content, which is in the form of dictionary
print signin_response.content

#according to the output, you may have ideas to judge whether login or not, according to the keys
#one way to fetch the value of key is:
print signin_response.json()[u'reply_msg']#assume reply_msg is one of the keys
```